# Use of undefined constant in laravel blade directive

Tags: laravel, switch-statement, laravel-blade, directive

In my blade I have

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 5px 10px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px;">
@identifier_prefix($order->pickup_time)
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In the AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
  Blade::directive('identifier_prefix', function ($pickup_time) {
    $prefix = '';
    switch($pickup_time){
      case '9u - 10u30':
      $prefix = 'O';
      break;
      case '10u30 - 12u':
      $prefix = 'V';
      break;
      case '12u - 14u30':
      $prefix = 'M';
      break;
      case '14u30 - 17u':
      $prefix = 'N';
      break;
      case '17u - 19u':
      $prefix = 'A';
      break;
      default:
      $prefix = 'ERROR';
      break;
    }
    return "<?php echo $prefix; ?>";
  });
}
```

I get an error returned saying

```
Use of undefined constant ERROR - assumed 'ERROR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

I'm no backend developer, so not much experience with php and blade. But can't understand why I'm getting an error printed. Not even the string 'ERROR' from the default statement, but an actual error.
Also, the default statement should not even be executed normally... So what's wrong here?

Now it becomes funny: I tried to echo $pickup_time directly from the directive like

```
Blade::directive('identifier_prefix', function ($pickup_time) {
    $prefix = 0;
    echo $pickup_time;
    //other code
```

and I get $order->pickup_time returned as a string...

How is this possible... Tried putting everything inside {} and without or with and echo... Tried everything... I'm getting lost.

Comment: Did you at one time have `$prefix = ERROR;` in your code? Do you run `php artisan view:clear` after making changes? (Couldn't read any comments on your other question since you deleted it)

Comment: This question extended the previous, that's why I deleted it. I run php artisan view:clear everytime I change something, $prefix is never used anywhere else...

Comment: Does it work if you change it to simply `return $prefix;`?

Comment: Also, removing the default statement of the switch, I get a "syntax error, unexpected ';' " referring to @identifier_prefix($order->pickup_time) in the blade file...

Comment: You need to echo it as a string, use `return "<?php echo \"{$prefix}\" ?>";`

Comment: @TimLewis with return $prefix; I always get 'ERROR' echoed. Because $order->pickup_time as a string is compared to the cases for some reason

Comment: @kerbh0lz gives me the same result as return $prefix; It's just that the switch is not comparing its case values with the value inside $order->pickup_time but with "$order->pickup_time"... I don't get it

Comment: Hm, works fine for me, shows ERROR in my blade. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @kerbh0lz yes I also get ERROR in my blade now I've removed the <php ?> in the return. But the switch is still not working. It's not using the value of the variable but the variable name as string

Comment: Is it because of the @foreach where I pass the variable to the custom directive?

Comment: Wow when writing this: @identifier_prefix(9u - 10u30) in the blade (No quotes), I get 'O' returned...

Comment: Use `return "<?php echo \"{$pickup_time}\" ?>";` to see what `$pickup_time` actually looks like. When using `@identifier_prefix('17u - 19u')` for testing in my blade this will output `'17u - 19u'` - including the quotes. Might be easier/less stressful to just use a Blade Component instead of a directive

Comment: @kerbh0lz <?php echo \"{$pickup_time}\" ?> returns me the pickup_time indeed, nice! But I can't write switch({$pickup_time}) to get the switch to use the variable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up trying. It just seems you cannot use variables inside a directive, what I can't believe...
But for everyone else in the future who encounters this problem: I solved it in the end just by writing:

```
@switch($order->pickup_time)
      @case('9u - 10u30')
        O
        @break
      @case('10u30 - 12u')
        V
        @break
      @case('12u - 14u30')
        M
        @break
      @case('14u30 - 17u')
        N
        @break
      @case('17u - 19u')
        A
        @break
      @default
          <span style="color: red;">Something went wrong</span>
  @endswitch
```

... and not using a directive